# How to select a row or column of a table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to know if each player has **inactive** or **longinactive** state and if it does, click the green eye: (see 3rd image)

[image: Here are all the players]

[image: none]

Eye icon, which is icon.icon_eye.hueRotate

[image: icon eye]

Then, I tried some codes like this one:

```
    if(td.playername.js_playerName6.longinactive) {
    // code to be executed if condition is true
console.log('OK');
} 
else {
    // code to be executed if condition is false
console.log('FUCK');}
```

But I got this error:

[image: But I got this error]

Then I tried this:

```
$("tr:contains('playername.js_playerName3.longinactive')" ).css( "display", "none" );
```

Just in case, I wanted to change something in a td or tr because if it worked I maybe could figure out a way to modify what I want to accomplish.

BTW, my main problem here is I don't know how to handle table rows nor columns.

FULL CODE of player 3 (all are the same I believe, except that the name changes)

```
    <tr class="row inactive_filter 

                        ">
                                                                        <td class="position js_no_action ">3</td>
                            <td rel="planet3" class="tooltipRel
                                       tooltipClose
                                       tooltipRight
                                       js_hideTipOnMobile
                                       microplanet
                                       js_planet3
                                       colonized
                                       " data-planet-id="34478246" colspan="1">
                                <div class="ListImage">
                                    <a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="sendShips(
                                                    6,
                                                    1,
                                                    465,
                                                    3,
                                                    1,
                                                    20
                                                            ); return false;">
                                        <img class="planetTooltip dry_9" src="https://gf2.geo.gfsrv.net/cdndf/3e567d6f16d040326c7a0ea29a4f41.gif" alt="" height="33" width="38">
                                    </a>

                                </div>
                                        <div id="ownFleetStatus_3_1" class="fleetAction">
            <img src="https://gf2.geo.gfsrv.net/cdndf/3e567d6f16d040326c7a0ea29a4f41.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="">
        </div>
                                <div id="planet3" style="display: none;" class="htmlTooltip galaxyTooltip">
    <h1>Planeta: <span class="textNormal">MAHOU</span></h1>
    <div class="splitLine"></div>
    <ul class="ListImage">
        <li><span id="pos-planet">[1:465:3]</span></li>
        <li><img class="planetTooltip dry_9" src="https://gf2.geo.gfsrv.net/cdndf/3e567d6f16d040326c7a0ea29a4f41.gif" alt="" height="33" width="38"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ListLinks">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="sendShips(6,1,465,3,1,20);return false">Espionaje</a></li><li><a href="https://s106-es.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=messages&amp;ajax=1&amp;messageId=27425792&amp;tabid=20" class="overlay">Informe de espionaje</a></li><li><a href="https://s106-es.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=fleet1&amp;galaxy=1&amp;system=465&amp;position=3&amp;type=1&amp;mission=1">Atacar</a></li><li><a href="https://s106-es.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=fleet1&amp;galaxy=1&amp;system=465&amp;position=3&amp;type=1&amp;mission=3">Transporte</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="planetname ">
                                                                    MAHOU
                                                            </td>

                                                     <td class="moon js_moon3 js_no_action">
                                        <div id="ownFleetStatus_3_3" class="fleetAction">
            <img src="https://gf2.geo.gfsrv.net/cdndf/3e567d6f16d040326c7a0ea29a4f41.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="">
        </div>
                            </td>
                                                <td class="debris js_debris3 ">
                                    <div id="ownFleetStatus_3_2" class="fleetAction">
            <img src="https://gf2.geo.gfsrv.net/cdndf/3e567d6f16d040326c7a0ea29a4f41.gif" width="12" height="12" alt="">
        </div>
                                                    </td>
                        <td class="playername
                                   js_playerName3
                                                                                                                                                longinactive
                                                               ">
                                                                                                                    <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="tooltipRel tooltipClose tooltipRight js_hideTipOnMobile" rel="player148501">
                                    <span class="status_abbr_longinactive">KAISER</span>
                                </a>
                                                        <span class="status">
                                                                    (<span class="status_abbr_longinactive"><span class="status_abbr_longinactive tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile" title="Inactivo 28 días">I</span></span>)
                                                            </span>
                                                            <div id="player148501" style="display: none;" class="htmlTooltip galaxyTooltip">
        <h1>Jugadores: <span>KAISER</span></h1>
        <div class="splitLine"></div>
        <ul class="ListLinks">
            <li class="rank">Clasificación: <a href="https://s106-es.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=highscore&amp;site=20&amp;searchRelId=148501">1933</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sendMail js_openChat tooltip" data-playerid="148501">Escribir mensaje</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://s106-es.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=buddies&amp;action=7&amp;id=148501&amp;ajax=1" class="overlay" data-overlay-title="Solicitud de amigo a jugador">Solicitud de amigos</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://s106-es.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=ignorelist&amp;action=1&amp;id=148501">Ignorar jugador</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
                                                    </td>
                        <td class="allytag
                                   js_allyTag3
                                                                                                  ">
                                                    </td>
                        <td class="action" colspan="2">
                            <span>
                                                                                                                                                                                                        <a class="tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile espionage" title="Espionaje" href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="sendShips(
                                                       6,
                                                       1,
                                                       465,
                                                       3,
                                                       1,
                                                       20
                                                   ); return false;">
                                                    <span class="icon icon_eye hueRotate"></span>
                                                </a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sendMail js_openChat tooltip" data-playerid="148501" title="Escribir mensaje"><span class="icon icon_chat"></span></a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <a class="tooltip overlay buddyrequest" title="Enviar solicitud de amigo" href="https://s106-es.ogame.gameforge.com/game/index.php?page=buddies&amp;action=7&amp;id=148501&amp;ajax=1" data-overlay-title="Solicitud de amigo a jugador">
                                                    <span class="icon icon_user"></span>
                                                </a>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <span class="tooltip js_hideTipOnMobile overlay missleattack" title="Ataque con misiles" data-overlay-modal="true">
                                                        <span class="icon icon_missile grayscale"></span>
                                                    </span>

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if an element has a class you do this:

```
$('td.playername').hasClass('someclass');
```

But in your case the td itself does not have a class inactive or longactive, it is.
So in your case you can do:

```
// this means that try to find a child within td.playername that has a class that we are looking for, and .length means that it is found if is it more than 0 (true)
if ($('td.playername').find('span.inactive, span.longactive').length) {
  console.log('found my class');
} else {
  console.log(':(');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this i hope this will work for you.

```
 $('body').on('click','.playername',function(){

 var result= $(this).closest('tr')
.find('td.playername')
.hasClass('someclass');

 if(result) {
    // code to be executed if condition is true
console.log('OK');
} 
else {
    // code to be executed if condition is false
console.log('Not Found');
}

});
```

Comment: @Fabian Montossi try this answer